# Badge for getting your answer accepted after another answer was accepted

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Today I found a question that already had an accepted answer. I thought I had a better answer, so I posted my answer anyway. The OP liked my answer and accepted it. I felt very proud of this and thought that I probably earned a badge for this, but I didn't.

Shouldn't there be a badge for this? I consider it something of an accomplishment. Also I think we want to encourage users to give a better answer if they have one even if there is an accepted answer already.

Surely I can't be the only one that thinks this badge is a good idea.

Comment: I know that a downvote on meta means that you disagree, but a comment or answer to explain why would be nice.

Comment: I propose the name "Dirty Rotten Accept Stealer" for this badge.  I suppose I've had this happen to me more times than I've done it.  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Encouraging users to post better answers even if another answer was already accepted is a good thing. But what if a question-poser accepts each answer once? That's a lot of badges.

Maybe a **"posted X answers that got upvoted/accepted after another answer was already accepted"** badge would encourage the same behaviour, while limiting the abuse?

Comment: I think that's actually even better, since it doesn't rely on the questioner coming back and changing the answer.

Comment: As @Grace Note points out, this would be a cousin of Revival/Necromancer, but focused on _broad_ behavior rather than individual.

Comment: the `Populist` badge could be defined as a variation of that, considering the fence-sitting on upvotes/acceptance: `Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x`. Need a persistence and a little ambition to achieve this, though.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: also, Populist targets answers which already have answers voted up to at least "Nice Answer"; this would be more for low-scoring accepted answers.

Answer (score 4):

I think Photo-SE could benefit from this. There's a number of older questions where the answer was accepted hastily; it would nice to see some more encouragement for people to provide better answers. (Populist has some pretty steep requirements.)

Comment: You could instead qualify for Revival/Necromancer (though based on votes, not acceptance) in those scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

I'm ambivalent toward the idea. <s>I mean, you've earned the (rep cap immune) 15 reputation points already.</s>

What happens if the asker changes his mind and re-accepts the original accepted answer? Should you lose the badge?

Frankly, I'd rather see a badge for the poor schlub who had his accepted answer taken away.

Comment: I don't agree with the "you already got rep so why should you get a batch" idea. If that's the metric, then the vast majority of badges would disappear.

Comment: The author of the original accepted answer doesn't lose the rep does he? I don't know, but I think if you've earned it you shouldn't lose it. Also I don't think it's a very common scenario that the OP would change his mind like that.

Comment: Yes. You lose the rep if your answer is "un-accepted".

Comment: Ok, it's never happened to me, so I didn't know.